# Discord.js Editing an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am fully aware this is not a new question.

I've gone through the documentation and a thousand other questions on this topic and nothing has worked for me.

The "edit" function presents no errors or even warnings.  It runs and embed isn't altered.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Worker Thread:

```js
async function run() {
  while (1) {
    include.globalVars.con.query(`SELECT * FROM interactable`, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      rows.forEach((row) => {
        switch (parseInt(row.status)) {
          case 0: {
            //New session setting to main menu
            edit(row.message, row.channel, row.guild, "========================================\nWelcome!\n========================================");
            include.globalVars.sql = `UPDATE interactable SET status = '1' WHERE id = '${row.id}'`;
            include.globalVars.con.query(include.globalVars.sql)
            break;
          }
        }
      })
    })
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}
async function edit(id, channel1, guild, content) {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 7000));
  console.log(content)
  client.channels.resolve(`${channel1}`).fetch(`${id}`).then(msg => {
    var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`${content}`)
    msg.edit(`${id}`);
  });
}
```

Main Thread:

```js
var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Interactive Admin:")
  .setAuthor("")
  .setColor(0x089fef)
  .setDescription(content)
  .setTimestamp();
include.globalVars.message.channel.send({ embed }).then((sentEmbed) => {
  sentEmbed.react("✅");
  sentEmbed.react("⬅️");
  sentEmbed.react("⬆️");
  sentEmbed.react("⬇️");
  sentEmbed.react("➡️");
  sentEmbed.react("❌");
  include.globalVars.msgid = sentEmbed.id;
  include.globalVars.sql = `INSERT INTO interactable (user, status, option, message, channel, guild) VALUES ("${include.globalVars.user}", "0", "0", "${include.globalVars.msgid}", "${include.globalVars.message.channel.id}", "${include.globalVars.message.guild.id}")`;
  include.globalVars.con.query(include.globalVars.sql);
  resolve(include.globalVars.msgid);
});
```

Comment: You might consider using [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) instead of worker threads and an infinite loop.

Comment: I think instead of `client.channels.resolve(…).fetch(…)`, you meant `client.channels.resolve(…).messages.fetch(…)`